# Using delegates to communicate between forms

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates

This will be a simple question. I have two forms. Form2 passes a string to Form1. Form1 then displays the inputted string in a MessageBox.

My code in **form2**:

```
public delegate void PassData(object o);
public PassData pd;
public Form2()
{
    pd("Hello World");
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

And in **form1**:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var f2 = new Form2();
    f2.pd = Arrive;
    f2.Show();
}

public void Arrive(object o)
{
    MessageBox.Show(o.ToString());
}
```

**The problem:** An unhandled exception of type System.NullReferenceException, at `pd("Hello World");`
I get it that it's null, but why is that a problem? I passed in a value in Form2's constructor to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I passed in a value in Form2's constructor to it.

No, you passed it after you initialized `Form2`. When the constructor of `Form2` is called, your `pd` value is still `null`, hence the `NullReferenceException`.

This line:

```
var f2 = new Form2();
```

Causes this to run:

```
public Form2()
{
    pd("Hello World");
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

What you actually want is to pass it as a parameter to `Form2`'s constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var f2 = new Form2(Arrive);
    f2.Show();
}

public Form2(Passdata passData)
{
    pd = passData;
    pd("Hello World");
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: On top of that, you might want to a) enforce that the constructor argument for `passData` be not null and b) make the `pd` field `private` to prevent it from being reset to `null` from outside of the class. (Besides all this it's quite common to check delegates/event handlers for `null` before invoking them -- like `if (pd != null) { pd("Hello World"); }` -- if "no handler" is a valid option).

Comment: It works, and I will make those changes suggested by Matthias, too. Thank you, both of you!